# How to use phone mask in Angular 2 Ionic 2 RC 2

Tags: jquery, angular, input, ionic2, mask

I want to use phone mask on my input value. I'm bad with Angular 2 experience. How to apply input mask like +7(999)999-99-99 like it was in jquery inputMask plugin?

Comment: hi! did u find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

For Angular2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-input-mask

Like this;

```js
$('#phone').mask("+0(000)000-00-00")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone"/>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually your mask needs to be like this: $('#phone').mask("+0(000)000-00-00")

Comment: @IgorEscobar I update my answer and thanks for this useful plugin.

Comment: it says to import jquery. What do they mean by that i am confused