# Input with formatted text and numeric keyboard on mobile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-input

I need to display an `input` that has the following features:

1. accept only numbers so that the value entered will be propagated to the `controller` variable as a numeric type
2. display the number with commas (thousand separator, i.e. 1000 => 1,000)
3. on mobile - open a numeric keyboard when focused

So I tried both `<input type="text">` and `<input type="number">` but each has its own pros and cons:

- `<input type="text">`:

  - **PROS:** Can be formatted and controlled using directives so it would only accept numbers, display the value as needed and propagate the value as required.
  - **CONS:** Doesn't open the numeric keyboard on mobile devices, needs custom directives and logic to handle user input
- `<input type="number">`:

  - **PROS:** Since I'm dealing with numbers, it seems like the logical choice. It opens the numeric keyboard as required
  - **CONS:** I couldn't find a way to make it display a formatted number

I'm currently using the `<input type="text">` with the following directive:

```
 app.directive('commaParse', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            //allow only numbers
            elem.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            //prevent pasting text
            elem.bind('paste', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            //handle user input
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                var res = $filter("number")(ctrl.$modelValue);
                return res;
            });

            //handle value changes in code
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                var res = $filter("number")(plainNumber);
                elem.val(res);
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I've tried changing the `inputmode` and the `lang` attributes but without success.
So the question is: how can I make my input display the formatted value as required **and** pop the numeric keyboard on mobile?

Comment: an input box is not supposed to display a formatted value. that would require it to allow letters and ignore validation which misses the point. you can just display the formatted value next to the input field. or replace it if it has been submitted. an alternative for eg. currency is to pre- and append the input box with text values, like ksh [input-box-here] ,-

Comment: I hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787495/how-to-use-phone-mask-in-angular-2-ionic-2-rc-2/43737803#43737803